# Where/How did the Red Skull find Captain America's old shield?

Tags: marvel, comics, captain-america

In the comic series ***Wolverine: Old Man Logan Issue#7***, we are introduced to President Red Skull. The issue starts off fifty years in the past (relative to the Old Man Logan's time) where the *Red Skull kills Captain America* and in the present day wears Cap's cowl as a trophy.

Later we se that a large number of heroes have fallen and the Skull has a trophy room full of their uniforms/armours and his greatest trophy, Captain America's shield is at the top.

[image]

In a wider shot, we see that his collection has a lot of trophies ranging from Silver Surfer's board to Ghost Rider's jacket. I spotted Captain America's first shield (the triangular sorta shield which he used before getting the circular one shown below)

[image]

It is quite logical that he got the new shield when he killed Captain America. But how and where was he able to get this old shield?

Comment: Possibly in this alternate universe, Steve kept the older shield too.

Comment: I'm glad Dr. Doom's equipment seems to be missing among it.

Answer (score 1):

Captain America used at least four of these types of shields, which could be a contender.

### The Originally-appearing Shield (Cap’s 2nd Triangle Shield) Was Destroyed by Mr. Hyde During “Avengers Under Siege”

Captain America’s original shield was destroyed.
[image: Cap’s Original]
This event occurred in [Avengers #275](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers_Vol_1_275), part of the status-quo breaking “Avengers Under Siege” multi-part event, where the Avengers have a really bad week when Masters of Evil succeed in putting Hercules in a coma and Mr. Hyde beats Jarvis nearly to death, giving him traumatic brain injury. Mr. Hyde crumples up the original shield; presumably this event occurred in the Old Man Logan “past history” continuity:
[image: Hyde Destroys Original Shield, Avengers v.1, 275]

This shield was later plucked from time and later restored by Zemo in Thunderbolts #105 (Oct. 2006), and eventually was used by *Young Avenger*, Patriot. It could be a candidate.

Also numerous variants of the original shield were also used by Cap. Also, given the shield was not obliterated or otherwise disintegrated, it’s possible that someone could have “uncrumpled” the thing, although that has not happened to date in comics.

### The Second “First Shield”

[image: Retcon Wakanda Shield]

2010’s *Captain America/Black Panther: Flags of Our Fathers* showed it was the Red Skull who crushed Cap’s WW2 “first shield.”

[image: Second First Shield]

The Skull, having crushed this one might have recovered and uncrumpled it.

### Smithsonian Replica

[image]

In *Captain America*, vol. 3, a third triangle shield, a replica, was placed in Smithsonian and was used by Cap when Hydra attacked the museum. It was destroyed by Kree a few issues later in vol. 3, #8. This one could have been repaired by the Skull.

.*IF*. *Old Man Logan* faithfully follows 616 events, the most likely candidate is the “second first shield” crushed by the Skull himself, because of its personal association to the Skull’s past victory in destroying it. But it could just as easily be one of the others.

### Most Recent

[image]
It could be Steve Rogers’ most recent shield, with a coat of paint.