# What are these uniforms/artifacts collected by Red Skull in the "Old Man Logan" storyline?

Tags: marvel, comics, object-identification, old-man-logan

Following up to my previous question ([here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185116/where-how-did-the-red-skull-find-captain-americas-old-shield)), I was able to identify most of the *trophies* collected by the Red Skull from the fallen heroes.

[image: Red Skull collection of trophies]

I am not able to place the Book/Box with a "D" on it (right below the Hulk's shorts), the arrow-pointed curvy thing (below the Punisher's t-shirt), the sword and the weird looking cloth/cape beside Cap's old shield. To be more clear, I have marked all of them in the image above.

Can someone help me identify the heroes to whom these things belonged before the fell?

Comment: I don't read comics much, but since the collection includes body parts the curvy thing with a point to it might be Nightcrawlers tail.

Comment: "My wife thinks..." Who the heck is Red Skull's wife!!?

Comment: @Skooba “Mrs. Skull,” of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Nightcrawler's tail (and it's immediately below Angel's wings, by the way)
- Darkhold Book
- Ebony blade

No idea where the rags are from, but they could be related to the stick immediately to the side.

Comment: Could the "rags" be a Carol Danvers era [Ms. Marvel](http://marvel.com/universe/Ms._Marvel_(Carol_Danvers)) costume?

Comment: @eshier unlikely. Because her emblem/costume is already there (just below The Thing's hand).

Comment: @motoDrizzt: thanks! I thought that the staff beside the rags belonged to Gambit. So as you said, the rags may belong to him as well.

Comment: @Shreedhar I assumed, due to the timing, that she was still Ms. Marvel with the lightning bolt when Old Man Logan came out.  Likewise, that there was a male Captain Marvel with the star at the time (a Skrull appartently?).  I'll admit I'd stopped paying attention to comics by then so my cursory look in Wikipedia could be off.